# Why does the list of Ignored Tags disappear in the sidebar after page refresh?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, ignored-tags

I was setting up some ignored tags today, and I noticed that after adding an ignored tag through the sidebar UI, the Ignored Tags section disappears after you refresh the page, and won't show up again until you click the "edit" button to edit your favorite/ignored tags again (see screenshots).

**Before (after adding ignored tag)**

[image: Before]

**After page refresh**

[image: After]

I've reproduced the behaviour in both:

1. Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m
2. Opera 31.0

so I assume that this isn't specific to a particular browser. I've also reproduced the behaviour here on MSE, as well as Stack Overflow, so I assume that it's not specific to a particular exchange site either.

**So is this a bug, or is this the intended behaviour?** If intended, what's the rationale behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. There was a commit dated 2014-01-09 titled "move ignored tags out of sidebar and into footer". Not being at the company at that time, I can't tell you what the official rationale was, but I can tell you my personal take on it.

---

To me, the rationale behind *showing* your favourite tags is that you can click on them to hone in on questions for that tag (or tags, if you select a wildcard tag).

You probably will never want to hone in on ignored tags. Showing them will just waste screen space (at best), or be a visual annoyance.

Comment: While true, I would still like to see what I ignore. Feature request asking to add it somehow has any chance in your opinion?

Comment: While we're add it, can this question be merged into the dupe target please? Or make this the canonical. It is confusing to have this question marked as the duplicate, and yet be the only question that actually has an authoritative answer.